# How to consume JSON from WCF service

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a function which connects to a WCF Service and then is supposed to return data to the webpage. My issue is that after receiving a valid response from the service, I cannot "grab" and manipulate that data.

```
function checkStatus(tempStatus, tempName, tempID, arrayLength){

var statusInText;
//alert('checkStatus function running');
$.getJSON('127.0.0.1'+ '/' + tempStatus, function(data){
    statusInText = data.GetStatesResult.State_Name
    alert('The status in Text value is ' + statusInText);
    placeCrewInArray(statusInText, tempName, tempID, arrayLength);      
});
}
```

I receive the error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'State_Name' of undefined**.

The JSON that is returned looks like this `{"getStatesResult":[{"Reference":"Call,work,shift","State_Name":"Active    ","id":1}]}`

I am unsure how I can get the state name from the returned JSON. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use your browser's debugger to check the value of `data`. You're not getting what you think you're getting. My guess is that either (1) nothing is getting sent back or (2) it is getting sent back with one level less than you expect (ie `data.State_Name`)

Comment: @J.DavidSmith `data: Object
getStatesResult: Array[1]
0: Object
Reference: "TCall,TCwork,shift"
State_Name: "Active    "
id: 1`

That was what was returned, so data is being returned. Just accessing it is escaping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try grabbing the data like so:

```
statusInText = data.getStatesResult[0].State_Name
```

You had a capital "G", when it actuality it is "getStatesResult". This then has an array of objects, so reference index 0, then `State_Name`

Here's a demo with your JSON logging the result you want: http://jsfiddle.net/nvkB6/

Comment: Thanks. You fixed it I totally forgot about the array. I had been looping through json earlier so I didn't need to reference the position when I used $.each()

Answer (score 2):

Your getting the error because `getStatesResult` property in JSON returns an array of objects and you are referencing a single object property which doesnt exist. Try this:

```
data.getStatesResult[0].State_Name
```